# Where can I find Ghost/Poison/Psychic type Pokémon?

Tags: pokemon-go

I know you can find water Pokémon near water, and grass Pokémon near... well grass. But what about Ghost/Poison/Psychic (let's just say "GPP" for short) type Pokémon?

I heard a rumor that you can find GPP Pokémon at night, but the only GPP Pokémon I've caught have just been in random suburb areas during the daytime, along with grass type Pokémon. Is there a specific location where you can find GPP type Pokémon? Or are they just rare and randomly placed?

Answer (score 7):

I think you will find this link helpful: http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/04/pokemon-go-types.html

It has a chart at the top showing what percentage of Kanto pokemon belong in each type. Below, it shows a list of all Pokemon in the game and after that there is a chart showing what type of Pokemon to expect in various Biomes.

Happy Hunting!

## **Possible Types**

**Normal**

> Boundaries, Landuse, Places, Roads, Transit, College, Commercial,
> Common, Footway, Hospital, Hotel, Library, Major Road, Minor Road,
> Pedestrian, Pitch, Playa, Recreation Area, Retail, Runway, School,
> Sports Center, Stadium, University

**Grass**

> Landmass, Farm, Farmland, Farmyard, Forest, Garden, Golf Course,
> Grass, Meadow, Nature Reserve, Park, Path, Playground, Residential,
> Wood

**Bug**

> Farm, Farmland, Farmyard, Forest, Garden, Golf Course, Grass, Nature
> Reserve, Park, Path, Playground, Wood

**Water**

> Water, Basin, Canal, Dock, Drain, Glacier, Lake, Ocean, Reservoir,
> River, Riverbank, Stream

**Flying**

> Farm, Farmland, Farmyard, Forest, Garden, Grass, Nature Reserve, Park,
> Wood

**Rock**

> Building, Landmass, Highway, Industrial, Parking, Quarry, Railway,
> Urban Area

**Ground**

> Landmass, Ditch, Land, Parking, Playground, Railway, Taxiway, Urban
> Area

**Fairy**

> POIs, Cemetery, Place of Worship

**Dark**

> Cemetery, Cinema, Theatre

**Steel**

> Building, Railway

**Dragon**

> POIs

**Ghost**

> Cemetery

**Ice**

> Glacier

**Psychic**

> *Hospital?*

**Electric**

> Industrial

**Fire**

> *Residential?*

**Poison**

> Wetland

Comment: I suck at formatting lol, I couldn't figure out how to make a table. Do you know of a way to make it look prettier?

Comment: No worries! Haha, I'll edit it.

Comment: Oh jeez, so fire Pokémon are all but nonexistent then?

Comment: The only fire pokemon I've seen were the shadow of **Vulpix** near a residential area far north of where I live, **Growlithe** from a 5km egg and my **Charmander**.

Comment: While I really like this list, I don't think it is accurate when it comes to the Ghost type Pokemon. I've been in a graveyard and have not seen any Ghost type. But I have found a Ghastly off a city street, and a Haunter at my church. So it really seems that it's just random. But I'm still curious if they spawn anywhere in particular.

Comment: Oh yeah, because *everyone* just has access to a freakin' glacier. =P

Comment: @HunterTurner Yeah, I think you're right. I've caught Ghastly near my house during the night time. And seen the shadow of Haunter. They could be randomly spawned at night time.

Comment: @Sync Well I caught both of mine during the day, haha.

Comment: @HunterTurner lol ghost pokemon are weird. Well I guess its just Ghastly and its evolutions.

Comment: I'm also a bit skeptical about the pokemon types / locations. Hasn't exactly been true in my experience and I'm worried this website (or some other website, which this website got the info from) made it up or just did a lot of liberal conjecturing.

Comment: What might an SOI be?

Answer (score 0):

Are there any other ghost types in Gen 1 besides the Gastly family? Anyways, I've found a few in urban locations and a few in suburbs. I have also heard that they are more common at night. I can't say for sure because I've largely been hunting in the evenings so my 'data' would be biased.

Comment: The only time I saw some Gastly was near a mall between 9:00 p.m. and 10:00 p.m.. Since I have only hunt was after 8:00 p.m., can't tell if they spawn at daytime.

Comment: I saw one during the daytime on a Saturday, but it ran away before I could find it.

Answer (score 0):

The only current ghost type Pokémon are from generation 1 (the Gastly family - Gastly, Haunter, and Gengar). These can be caught at any time of day, although they are more likely to appear at night. I am not aware of any location restrictions for Ghost-type Pokémon at this time. Thanks to user Ellesedil for pointing this out with evidence of daytime appearance [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274542/do-ghost-type-pok%C3%A9mon-appear-only-at-night/274543#274543).

Furthermore, there is no hard evidence that Gastlys (or other Pokémon) appear more often at night. Several sources (such as [Polygon's guide](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/6/12105992/pokemon-go-guide-faq-ios-android)) claim that Gastly spawns more frequently at night, but don't offer any source or evidence, so take this how you will. Personally I have seen two Gastlys at night and two during the early afternoon, so it is entirely possible that any night time relation is false.

Edit: After the edit to the question, my response is that there is no such delineation as "Purple Type" and that Psychic and Ghost are different types and have different spawning/location-time rules.

Comment: You seams to know what you are taking about. Do you have any sources or it's from personnal experience?

Comment: It's on the website somewhere I believe - specifically mentioned as a "night-time" Pokémon, I'll update my response if I can find it.

Comment: Keep me updated with what you find @turner, I'm not sure if the game goes by the TCG or if the types are split up.

Comment: @HunterTurner it uses the video game types (so geodude is rock/ground and not fighting) I don't know if it uses Gen 1 types or current types for things like Clefairy (which is fairy now, but used to be normal)

Comment: Yeah you're right @diego, I just found this which is super helpful http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/05/ghost-type-pokemon.html

Comment: I don't think I agree with your "at night" timing, as I caught one at 6:25 this morning in a rural gas station parking lot. :P

Comment: Your assertions about ghost type Pokemon is incorrect. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/274542/do-ghost-type-pok%C3%A9mon-appear-only-at-night/274543#274543

Comment: Thanks for your comment @Ellesedil - I actually caught one of these around 2:30 in the afternoon the other day, and forgot to update the comment, I have updated it to reflect the new information.

Answer (score 0):

For Poison:

I've know 2 locations at my town that have a ton of Nidoran spawns.
Zubat apparently spawns everywhere, day or night.

For Psychic:

I know 1 location which spawns a lot of Abras, another location that spawns a lot of Drowzees. Also caught a random Jynx at one point. Drowzee is more an urban area while Abra is more grassland.

For Ghost:

I cannot say for sure, I've seen Ghastly in all places I went to, its just super rare. Also I've noticed that Ghastly shows up around 2x-3x at night.