# What kind of areas have folks been finding Gastly's?

Tags: pokemon-go

Gengar is my #1 favorite, but I haven't been finding Gastly's =(. Where has everyone else been finding theirs? I thought Graveyards would be the place to look, but I just find Pidgeys.

Comment: Possible dup http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273802/where-can-i-find-purple-type-pokemon

Comment: That other question is too generalized. There is no "purple" Pokemon that lumps those 3 types together.

Comment: purple pokemon are any that are ghost, poison, or psychic. also the first answer addresses your question.

Comment: Fair, I just don't agree with it being a dupe since the other is way too general. Cheers.

Comment: I live in a random urban area, and I see ghastly all over. I'm not aware of anything interesting around my place.

Answer (score 3):

I have heard that they elected *not* to target ghost types to graveyards, so they wouldn't end up with legions of players traipsing through graveyards (that'd make for some bad publicity). Don't know where they tend to congregate, but I've read somewhere (yeah, I know, not the best sources) that ghost tend to appear after 8pm.

Answer (score 1):

I have found three (and seen many more) so far in the "historic" region of my town.

But since I can't confirm the relevance of the history, I'd say: "mid population, semi-urban, shopping district in eastern PA"

Gastly also spawn with much higher frequency at night, and I have seen them elsewhere around sunset.

Comment: I found one at a church and a hospital yesterday!