# Do ghost type Pokémon appear only at night?

Tags: pokemon-go

I've seen it mentioned in few answers here that ghost type Pokémon appear only at night. Is this true?

Comment: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/273802/where-can-i-find-purple-type-pokemon?rq=1

Comment: @Dragonrage: That question is about ghost, poison, and psychic type Pokemon. It's a little broad. My question is specific to ghost type Pokemon.

Comment: I have caught multiple gastly's in the morning and night and evening, as well as a couple of haunters in the afternoon... So I can attest to every answer that says no to this question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, it's not. For starters, here's a Gastly around 4pm in the afternoon.

[image: A Ghastly at 4 pm]

I've also been playing the game until 2 am every night since the game was released and haven't seen a single ghost-type Pokémon in the wild at night. It is doubtful that time of day is a factor for them, which means they're probably location dependent, just like other Pokémon.

Comment: Be (more) careful (compared to day) when playing at night :)

Answer (score 0):

As far as time of day and the appearance of Ghost (or Fairy)-type Pokémon goes, I definitely wouldn't fault anyone for thinking that there was a relationship there. Multiple [sites](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/6/12105992/pokemon-go-guide-faq-ios-android) have created [articles](http://www.mobipicker.com/pokemon-go-day-night-cycles-confirmed-footage-shows-ghastly-caught-night/) claiming as much, and it certainly makes sense that there would be a connection. Unfortunately, based on both my personal experience and evidence posted by other users on this site, there just doesn't appear to be one. I personally have caught two at night and one during the early afternoon, and seen another one on my proximity tracker during the day as well. Ellesedil's answer also provides evidence that Ghost Pokémon are not exclusively found at night.

Unfortunately I have no information about locations where Ghost Pokémon appear. I personally have caught Gastlys near a Park, near a historic landmark, and along a nondescript road near a school, so I can't even offer a guess in this regard. If anyone else has any information (preferably from reputable sources) please feel free to post it to augment our understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Well. Ghost pokemons doesnt only appear at night. Today I walked a pretty far distance looking for pokemons, and suddenly a ghastly popped up right infront of me in the middle of the day. I think you can get pretty much any pokemon at any point of the day regardless of your position. Maybe not water pokemons but.. hehe

Answer (score -1):

I've seen a rare chance of getting Ghost Type in the afternoon. None in the morning  for me. At night, at least 3 or more are nearby me, so I'd assume more appear at night, but not much during the day. The game has only been out for so long, so their's lots to explore!

Answer (score -1):

Oddly enough I have only seen ghost types during the middle of the day so I am not sure what the spawn conditions are.

Answer (score -1):

Adapted to location is highly debatable. I walked through a complete circuit *inside* a large cemetary, and caught absolutely none, except for a rattata and a pidgey. I walked enough inside to completely hatch a 2km pokemon and half of a 5km pokemon.

Answer (score -1):

No, they don't, I caught ghastly in the middle of the day.

Answer (score -1):

Ghost types have a spawn during the day, its just the spawn is relatively lower than the one at night which has less to the thought that they only spawn at night. The can be found but you have be a little more vigilant for them.

Comment: "its just the spawn is relatively lower than the one at night which has less to the thought that they only spawn at night."  How do you know this to be true?

Answer (score -1):

Any pokemon can spawn at any time of the day and anywhere, I don't believe that any pokemon in the game yet only spawns at a certain area.

I do think that ghost pokemon more frequently spawn at night though.

Comment: Do you have a source for this?

Answer (score -1):

My experience is certain types of Pokémon pop up in certain area more than other area.. but not necessarily relates to their genre.. (other wise where to find electric Pokémon?)  and no, ghost Pokémon doesn't pops up only at creepy places either..just random to time/location in general depend on their rarity.  it is more effective to have poke hunters share where they caught most of what Pokémon in what area, then we all can benefit.

Comment: just a P.S. I caught tangela and grimer at a market plaza parking lot at night (because I only go there at night)...but there's loads of magikarb pops up every 5-10 min as well, and loads of other water based pokemon pops up (dratini, mochop, goldee, squirtle, staryu, seel etc....only because there's two water fountain and seafood restaurant??  not so convincing...

Answer (score -2):

So ghost Pokemon are adapted to location just like every other Pokemon. they are usally found in cemetery's, abandon houses, dark. Secluded places like caves they are more  commonly found in those type of locations

Comment: I don't think the game can even tell if a house is abandoned or if you're in a cave. I don't think it tracks things like cemeteries either.